# Convert 3 bytes to int in go?

Tags: go, type-conversion, byte

I know how to use "encoding/binary" to convert 4 bytes to an int, etc.

What is the most efficient way to convert just 3 bytes to an int?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Little endian:

```
n := int(uint(b[0]) | uint(b[1])<<8 | uint(b[2])<<16))
```

Big endian:

```
n := int(uint(b[2]) | uint(b[1])<<8 | uint(b[0])<<16))
```